# Using JUnit annotations for ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 tests

Tags: android, junit

I use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 for testing my Android apps. Currently I create test methods by naming the methods testXXX where XXX is some arbitrary name. Is it possible to dispense with the "test" naming convention and annotate the method the way it's done with JUnit? I find this much better because I could create methods that do have testXXX names but wouldn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyCoolActivity> {

private MainActivity mActivity;

public MainActivityTest() {
    super(MainActivityTest.class);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    mActivity = getActivity();
}

@Test
public void checkPreconditions() {
    assertThat(mActivity, notNullValue());
    // Check that Instrumentation was correctly injected in setUp()
    assertThat(getInstrumentation(), notNullValue());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
}
```

add the dependencies in build.gradle

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
}

dependencies {
// Testing-only dependencies
// Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

@Before - This method is executed before each test. It is used to prepare the test environment (e.g., read input data, initialize the class).

@Test: The @Test annotation identifies a method as a test method.

@After:
This method is executed after each test. It is used to cleanup the test environment (e.g., delete temporary data, restore defaults). It can also save memory by cleaning up expensive memory structures.